# Text-align: center, with wrapper, Input Boxes & Button not centering themselves but logo centers fine

Tags: html, css, center, text-align

On this page I have a logo (image file, with a set height to fit better) which centers itself fine in its own div. This logo is wrapped in a wrapper div with `text-align: center` and centers fine. There are also 2 text input boxes with a search button wrapped in a separate div from the logo's, and they're also wrapped in the wrapper div, but when I load the page that div appears on the left side of the page.

If I comment out the `searchArea` div so the button and boxes are surrounded only by the wrapper, everything centers fine but gets stretched out because of the width property.

How do I get everything inside the `searchArea` div to center under the logo without losing the set styles for the `searchArea` class???

HTML:

```
<div id="logo" class="centerWrapper">
    <img id="logo" class="logo" src="img/TestAPICropped.png" alt="logo">
</div>

<div id="search" class="centerWrapper">
    <div id="searchArea" class="searchArea">
        <input type="text" class="inputBox" name="charName" placeholder="Character Name"><br>
        <input type="text" class="inputBox" name="realmName" placeholder="Realm Name"><br>
        <button type="button" class="searchButton">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.centerWrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
.logo {
    height: 46px;
}
.searchArea{
    margin-top: 0.8%;
    height: 125px;
    width: 340px;
}
input.inputBox {
    background-color: #0B122F;
    border-color: #877055;
    color: #4A4E5A;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    width: 72%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to horizontally center **[block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)** like [**`<div>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div), you're looking to the apply the **[`margin-left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-left)** and **[`marign-right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-right)** properties, both with `auto` values.

Normally you can use the shorthand **[`margin: 0 auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin)**, but considering you have a **[`margin-top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-top)** of `0.8%`, you need to specify both manually for your `.searchArea` selector.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.centerWrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
  height: 46px;
}

.searchArea {
  margin-top: 0.8%;
  height: 125px;
  width: 340px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

input.inputBox {
  background-color: #0B122F;
  border-color: #877055;
  color: #4A4E5A;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  width: 72%;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo" class="centerWrapper">
  <img id="logo" class="logo" src="img/TestAPICropped.png" alt="logo">
</div>

<div id="search" class="centerWrapper">
  <div id="searchArea" class="searchArea">
    <input type="text" class="inputBox" name="charName" placeholder="Character Name"><br>
    <input type="text" class="inputBox" name="realmName" placeholder="Realm Name"><br>
    <button type="button" class="searchButton">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

To horizontally center block elements you have to use margin: 0 auto; 
But there is margin-top: 0.8%; 
So you can use it together:

```
.searchArea {
    margin: 0.8% auto 0;
}
```

Good luck!)